# i am facing issue while running I am not able to solve this error

Tags: reactjs, express

```
evtools
response.js:41 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
    at Object.<anonymous> (response.js:41:1)
    at ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js (response.js:1105:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js (express.js:21:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at ./node_modules/express/index.js (index.js:11:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at ./src/components/admin/NewProduct.js (NewProduct.css?268e:45:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at ./src/App.js (App.css?da7c:45:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at ./src/index.js (index.css?02e3:45:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at 0 (store.js:46:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32:1)
    at main.chunk.js:1:57
```

```
/**
 * Response prototype.
 * @public
 */
var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype);

/**
 * Module exports.
 * @public
 */

module.exports = res;

/**
```

``

(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:57
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
console

console

```
response.js:41 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
    at Object.<anonymous> (response.js:41:1)
    at ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js (response.js:1105:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js (express.js:21:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at ./node_modules/express/index.js (index.js:11:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at ./src/components/admin/NewProduct.js (NewProduct.css?268e:45:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at ./src/App.js (App.css?da7c:45:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at ./src/index.js (index.css?02e3:45:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at 0 (store.js:46:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32:1)
    at main.chunk.js:1:57
``
```

response.js:41

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
at Object.<anonymous> (response.js:41:1)
at ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js (response.js:1105:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js (express.js:21:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./node_modules/express/index.js (index.js:11:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./src/components/admin/NewProduct.js (NewProduct.css?268e:45:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./src/App.js (App.css?da7c:45:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./src/index.js (index.css?02e3:45:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at 0 (store.js:46:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32:1)
at main.chunk.js:1:57
```

response.js:41

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
at Object.<anonymous> (response.js:41:1)
at ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js (response.js:1105:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js (express.js:21:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./node_modules/express/index.js (index.js:11:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./src/components/admin/NewProduct.js (NewProduct.css?268e:45:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./src/App.js (App.css?da7c:45:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./src/index.js (index.css?02e3:45:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at 0 (store.js:46:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32:1)
at main.chunk.js:1:57
```

response.js:41

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
at Object.<anonymous> (response.js:41:1)
at ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js (response.js:1105:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js (express.js:21:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./node_modules/express/index.js (index.js:11:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./src/components/admin/NewProduct.js (NewProduct.css?268e:45:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./src/App.js (App.css?da7c:45:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./src/index.js (index.css?02e3:45:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at 0 (store.js:46:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32:1)
at main.chunk.js:1:57
```

response.js:41

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
at Object.<anonymous> (response.js:41:1)
at ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js (response.js:1105:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js (express.js:21:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./node_modules/express/index.js (index.js:11:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./src/components/admin/NewProduct.js (NewProduct.css?268e:45:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./src/App.js (App.css?da7c:45:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at ./src/index.js (index.css?02e3:45:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
at 0 (store.js:46:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782:1)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32:1)
at main.chunk.js:1:57
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone from following lines of code are in your code remove them

```
 import response from { 'express' }
```

or

```
import e from 'express'
```

or

```
import { request } from 'express';
```